# Linking additional module against already built main microcontroller firmware

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, microcontroller, linker-scripts

I'm working on a bare-metal microcontroller project that needs to be able to execute a blob of code loaded at runtime. The basic implementation is simple enough - write a linker script that can handle it being loaded in to RAM somewhere, leave a little vector table at the beginning of the image, memcpy it in to place, and then from the main firmware read the vector table and jump in to the module's entry point.

My question comes with how to convince the linker for the module to allow calls back in to the main firmware (avoid duplicating utility functions, share data with main firmware, etc).

Suppose the main firmware has some function:

```cpp
int FunctionInMainFirmware() {
    return 1234;
}
```

The main firmware complies/links to produce an elf that's later objdump'd to a bin flashed to the microcontroller. As expected, the function ends up linked in the main firmware's flash:

`080b73b0 g     F .text 00000008 _Z22FunctionInMainFirmwarev`

So then we get to the loadable module:

```cpp
using myFunc = int(void);
static const myFunc* f = reinterpret_cast<myFunc*>(0x080b73b0);

int FunctionInLibrary() {
    return f();

    // How do I make this work?
    // return FunctionInMainFirmware();
}
```

This implementation works - the compiler correctly generates the call to the function in the main firmware. This is of course nasty and too unwieldy to do in the real world, but proved to me that if the code is generated how I want, it'll do what I want.

How do I convince the linker to treat my main firmware elf as if it was a static library? Essentially I just want it to read the linker map from the main firmware to resolve missing functions from the module.

I tried `-l:MyMainFirmware.elf`, which doesn't fail, but also doesn't produce a valid result:

- It copies the entire contents of the main firmware's elf. This makes sense since it sees sections it should copy (ie, .text), so it puts them in the output and re-links it.
- It doesn't link correctly, and does some weird math resulting in mangled addresses.

Is there some way to get the linker to just read the .map or .dmp files generated by the main build? Or to read the elf but ignore the contents, and only look at the symbol address (then don't futz with it)?

Comment: won't it stop working if the function address changes in the main firmware - which it will, every time you change the firmware?

Comment: @user253751 Sure, and it means that such a module needs to be replaced by a new module knowing the new firmware's entry points. -- Unfortunately the system's software architecture seems to lack to take the requirement of modules into account. Otherwise the firmware would have a vector table or a system call entry at a fixed address.

Comment: Are you aware that the ABI of the firmware needs to be compatible with the module's ABI? What if both are built with different compilers and/or options?

Comment: Write a little shell script that processes symbol table of the main application (using `nm` or similar) and creates a linker script with assignments for all the function names.  Include this generated linker file from your main linker script of the module.